# Comparing arrays in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for a way to make comparisons between arrays in arrays.

```
let small = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0]];

let large = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 0], [3, 2]];
```

For example, I would like to be able to find out how many of the arrays in `small` are found in `large`. Some function that, given the arrays above as arguments, would return `2`, since `[2, 2]` and `[3, 0]` from `small` are found in `large`.

How would you go about doing that?

Comment: You can turn `large` into a `Set` or `Object` with `large[0]` and `large[1]` as keys seperated with `-` and then do lookups using `small's` values

Comment: Have you made any attempt at solving it?

Comment: May be you could convert every subarray to a string with `join` function and then compare only strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert one of the arrays into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of hashes, and than [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the 2nd array using the set:

```js
const small = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0]];

const large = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 0], [3, 2]];

const containsCount = (arr1, arr2, hashFn) => {
  const arr1Hash = new Set(arr1.map(hashFn));
  
  return arr2.filter(s => arr1Hash.has(hashFn(s))).length;
}

const result = containsCount(small, large, ([a, b]) => `${a}-${b}`); 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what was going on here, but I like the solution. Learning a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```js
let small = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0]];
let large = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 0], [3, 2]];

let z = zeta(small, large);
console.log(z);

function zeta(a, b) {
  let join = m => m.join();
  let x = a.map(join);
  let y = b.map(join);
  
  return x.reduce((n, m) => (y.indexOf(m)>0) ? ++n : n, 0);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Turning the arrays into strings makes sense, but I'm struggling to make sense of the return statement.

Comment: [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a versatile method. I initialize a counter `n` to `0`, looping over `x[]` and testing if element `m` of `x[]` is in `y[]`. If so, `++` `n` else return `n` unmodified. `n` is implicitly returned by this use of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) thus `n`'s value is maintained in subsequent calls to the anonymous arrow function. Finally, `n` is returned by `reduce()` then returned by `zeta()`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `every` and `some` to compare the arrays with each other.

If you want to get an array containing the subarrays that match, use `filter`:

```
let result = small.filter(arr => 
  large.some(otherArr =>
    otherArr.length === arr.length && otherArr.every((item, i) => item === arr[i])
  )
);
```

Which *filters* the subarray from `small` that *some* subarray from `large` has the same `length` and the same elements/items.

**Demo:**

```js
let small = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0]];

let large = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 0], [3, 2]];

let result = small.filter(arr => 
  large.some(otherArr =>
    otherArr.length === arr.length && otherArr.every((item, i) => item === arr[i])
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

And if you want just a count, then use `reduce` instead of `filter` to count the mathched items (this makes use of the fact that the numeric value of `true` is `1` and that of `false` is `0`):

```
let count = small.reduce((counter, arr) => 
  counter + large.some(otherArr =>
    otherArr.length === arr.length && otherArr.every((item, i) => item === arr[i])
  )
, 0);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let small = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0]];

let large = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 0], [3, 2]];

let count = small.reduce((counter, arr) =>
  counter + large.some(otherArr =>
    otherArr.length === arr.length && otherArr.every((item, i) => item === arr[i])
  )
, 0);

console.log(count);
```

**Note:** If the subarrays contain only numbers, the code could be simplified to use `Array#toString` instead of `every` and `length` comparaison:

```
let result = small.filter(arr => large.some(otherArr => "" + otherArr === "" + arr));
```

Which casts both arrays into strings and compares the two strings instead. This can be used with the `reduce` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create two nesting map() function oute for small and inner for large then use JSON.stringify()

```
let small = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0]];
let large = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 0], [3, 2]];
var same=[];
    small.map(function(element){
        large.map(function(element2){
            if(JSON.stringify(element)==JSON.stringify(element2)){
        same.push(element);
  }
 });
});
console.log(same);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let small = [[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0]];

let large = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 0], [3, 2]];


let largeArrayStringForm = large.map(item => item.toString())
let matchingItems = small.filter(item => largeArrayStringForm.includes(item.toString()))

console.log(`matchCount: ${matchingItems.length}`)
```